# Independent conditions imposed by a collection of double points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let's consider the following statement : There exist a collection of $d$ points $\gamma \subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$, so that $h_{\Bbb P^n}(\gamma^{2} ,m) = \min\{(n+1)d, \binom {n+m}{n}\}$ implies for any general collection of $d$  points $\gamma \subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$, $h_{\Bbb P^n}(\gamma^{2} ,m) = \min\{(n+1)d, \binom {n+m}{n}\}$

Question: Is the above statement true?

If so then how to prove it explicitly? I guess we need to use semicontinuity of Hilbert function but I don't know how to use it. Can someone give reference on this?